# Hiding a Lua metatable and only exposing an object's attributes

Tags: lua, lua-table, metatable, lua-5.2

How do you create a Lua object that only exposes its attributes and not its methods? For example:

```lua
local obj = {
  attr1 = 1,
  attr2 = 2,
  print = function(...)
    print("obj print: ", ...)
  end,
}
```

Produces:

```lua
> for k,v in pairs(obj) do print(k, v) end
attr1   1
attr2   2
print   function: 0x7ffe1240a310
```

Also, is it possible to not use the colon syntax for OOP in Lua? I don't need inheritance, polymorphism, only encapsulation and privacy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I started out with the above question and after chasing down the rabbit hole, I was surprised by the limited number of examples, lack of examples for the various metamethods (i.e. `__ipairs`, `__pairs`, `__len`), and how few Lua 5.2 resources there were on the subject.

Lua can do OOP, but IMO the way that OOP is prescribed is a disservice to the language and community (i.e. in such a way as to support polymorphism, multiple inheritance, etc). There are very few reasons to use most of Lua's OOP features for most problems. It doesn't necessarily mean there's a fork in the road either (e.g. in order to support polymorphism there's nothing that says you have to use the colon syntax - you can fold the literature's described techniques in to the closure-based OOP method).

I appreciate that there are lots of ways to do OOP in Lua, but it's irritating to have there be different syntax for object attributes versus object methods (e.g. `obj.attr1` vs `obj:getAttr()` vs `obj.method()` vs `obj:method()`). I want a single, unified API to communicate internally and externally. To that end, [PiL 16.4's section on Privacy](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.4.html) is a fantastic start, but it's an incomplete example that I hope to remedy with this answer.

---

The following example code:

- emulates a class's namespace `MyObject = {}` and saves the object constructor as `MyObject.new()`
- hides all of the details of the objects inner workings so that a user of an object only sees a pure table (see `setmetatable()` and `__metatable`)
- uses closures for information hiding (see [Lua Pil 16.4](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.4.html) and [Object Benchmark Tests](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectBenchmarkTests))
- prevents modification of the object (see `__newindex`)
- allows for methods to be intercepted  (see `__index`)
- lets you get a list of all of the functions and attributes (see the 'key' attribute in `__index`)
- looks, acts, walks, and talks like a normal Lua table (see `__pairs`, `__len`, `__ipairs`)
- looks like a string when it needs to (see `__tostring`)
- works with `Lua 5.2`

Here's the code to construct a new `MyObject` (this could be a standalone function, it doesn't need to be stored in the `MyObject` table - there is absolutely nothing that ties `obj` once its created back to `MyObject.new()`, this is only done for familiarity and out of convention):

```lua
MyObject = {}
MyObject.new = function(name)
   local objectName = name

   -- A table of the attributes we want exposed
   local attrs = {
      attr1 = 123,
   }

   -- A table of the object's methods (note the comma on "end,")
   local methods = {
      method1 = function()
         print("\tmethod1")
      end,

      print = function(...)
         print("MyObject.print(): ", ...)
      end,

      -- Support the less than desirable colon syntax
      printOOP = function(self, ...)
         print("MyObject:printOOP(): ", ...)
      end,
   }

   -- Another style for adding methods to the object (I prefer the former
   -- because it's easier to copy/paste function()'s around)
   function methods.addAttr(k, v)
      attrs[k] = v
      print("\taddAttr: adding a new attr: " .. k .. "=\"" .. v .. "\"")
   end

   -- The metatable used to customize the behavior of the table returned by new()
   local mt = {
      -- Look up nonexistent keys in the attrs table. Create a special case for the 'keys' index
      __index = function(t, k)
         v = rawget(attrs, k)
         if v then
            print("INFO: Successfully found a value for key \"" .. k .. "\"")
            return v
         end
         -- 'keys' is a union of the methods and attrs
         if k == 'keys' then
            local ks = {}
            for k,v in next, attrs, nil do
               ks[k] = 'attr'
            end
            for k,v in next, methods, nil do
               ks[k] = 'func'
            end
            return ks
         else
            print("WARN: Looking up nonexistant key \"" .. k .. "\"")
         end
      end,

      __ipairs = function()
         local function iter(a, i)
            i = i + 1
            local v = a[i]
            if v then
               return i, v
            end
         end
         return iter, attrs, 0
      end,

      __len = function(t)
         local count = 0
         for _ in pairs(attrs) do count = count + 1 end
         return count
      end,

      __metatable = {},

      __newindex = function(t, k, v)
         if rawget(attrs, k) then
            print("INFO: Successfully set " .. k .. "=\"" .. v .. "\"")
            rawset(attrs, k, v)
         else
            print("ERROR: Ignoring new key/value pair " .. k .. "=\"" .. v .. "\"")
         end
      end,

      __pairs = function(t, k, v) return next, attrs, nil end,

      __tostring = function(t) return objectName .. "[" .. tostring(#t) .. "]" end,
   }
   setmetatable(methods, mt)
   return methods
end
```

And now the usage:

```lua
-- Create the object
local obj = MyObject.new("my object's name")

print("Iterating over all indexes in obj:")
for k,v in pairs(obj) do print('', k, v) end
print()

print("obj has a visibly empty metatable because of the empty __metatable:")
for k,v in pairs(getmetatable(obj)) do print('', k, v) end
print()

print("Accessing a valid attribute")
obj.print(obj.attr1)
obj.attr1 = 72
obj.print(obj.attr1)
print()

print("Accessing and setting unknown indexes:")
print(obj.asdf)
obj.qwer = 123
print(obj.qwer)
print()

print("Use the print and printOOP methods:")
obj.print("Length: " .. #obj)
obj:printOOP("Length: " .. #obj) -- Despite being a PITA, this nasty calling convention is still supported

print("Iterate over all 'keys':")
for k,v in pairs(obj.keys) do print('', k, v) end
print()

print("Number of attributes: " .. #obj)
obj.addAttr("goosfraba", "Satoshi Nakamoto")
print("Number of attributes: " .. #obj)
print()

print("Iterate over all keys a second time:")
for k,v in pairs(obj.keys) do print('', k, v) end
print()

obj.addAttr(1, "value 1 for ipairs to iterate over")
obj.addAttr(2, "value 2 for ipairs to iterate over")
obj.addAttr(3, "value 3 for ipairs to iterate over")
obj.print("ipairs:")
for k,v in ipairs(obj) do print(k, v) end

print("Number of attributes: " .. #obj)

print("The object as a string:", obj)
```

Which produces the expected - and poorly formatted - output:

```
Iterating over all indexes in obj:
    attr1   123

obj has a visibly empty metatable because of the empty __metatable:

Accessing a valid attribute
INFO: Successfully found a value for key "attr1"
MyObject.print():   123
INFO: Successfully set attr1="72"
INFO: Successfully found a value for key "attr1"
MyObject.print():   72

Accessing and setting unknown indexes:
WARN: Looking up nonexistant key "asdf"
nil
ERROR: Ignoring new key/value pair qwer="123"
WARN: Looking up nonexistant key "qwer"
nil

Use the print and printOOP methods:
MyObject.print():   Length: 1
MyObject.printOOP():        Length: 1
Iterate over all 'keys':
    addAttr func
    method1 func
    print   func
    attr1   attr
    printOOP        func

Number of attributes: 1
    addAttr: adding a new attr: goosfraba="Satoshi Nakamoto"
Number of attributes: 2

Iterate over all keys a second time:
    addAttr func
    method1 func
    print   func
    printOOP        func
    goosfraba       attr
    attr1   attr

    addAttr: adding a new attr: 1="value 1 for ipairs to iterate over"
    addAttr: adding a new attr: 2="value 2 for ipairs to iterate over"
    addAttr: adding a new attr: 3="value 3 for ipairs to iterate over"
MyObject.print():   ipairs:
1   value 1 for ipairs to iterate over
2   value 2 for ipairs to iterate over
3   value 3 for ipairs to iterate over
Number of attributes: 5
The object as a string: my object's name[5]
```

---

- Using OOP + closures is very convenient when embedding Lua as a facade or documenting an API.
- Lua OOP can also be very, very clean and elegant (this is subjective, but there aren't any rules with this style - you always use a `.` to access either an attribute or a method)
- Having an object behave exactly like a table is VERY, VERY useful for scripting and interrogating the state of a program
- Is extremely useful when operating in a sandbox

This style does consume slightly more memory per object, but for most situations this isn't a concern. Factoring out the metatable for reuse would address this, though the example code above doesn't.

A final thought. Lua OOP is actually very nice once you dismiss most of the examples in the literature. I'm not saying the literature is bad, btw (that couldn't be further from the truth!), but the set of sample examples in PiL and other online resources lead you to using only the colon syntax (i.e. the first argument to all functions is `self` instead of using a `closure` or `upvalue` to retain a reference to `self`).

Hopefully this is a useful, more complete example.

---

**Update (2013-10-08)**: There is one notable drawback to the closure-based OOP style detailed above (I still think the style is worth the overhead, but I digress): each instance must have its own closure. While this is obvious in the above lua version, this becomes slightly problematic when dealing with things on the C-side.

Assume we're talking about the above closure style from the C-side from here on out.  The common case on the C side is to create a `userdata` via `lua_newuserdata()` object and attach a metatable to the `userdata` via `lua_setmetatable()`. On face value this doesn't appear like a problem until you realize that methods in your metatable require an upvalue of the userdata.

```c
using FuncArray = std::vector<const ::luaL_Reg>;
static const FuncArray funcs = {
  { "__tostring", LI_MyType__tostring },
};

int LC_MyType_newInstance(lua_State* L) {
  auto userdata = static_cast<MyType*>(lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(MyType)));
  new(userdata) MyType();

  // Create the metatable
  lua_createtable(L, 0, funcs.size());     // |userdata|table|
  lua_pushvalue(L, -2);                    // |userdata|table|userdata|
  luaL_setfuncs(L, funcs.data(), 1);       // |userdata|table|
  lua_setmetatable(L, -2);                 // |userdata|
  return 1;
}

int LI_MyType__tostring(lua_State* L) {
  // NOTE: Blindly assume that upvalue 1 is my userdata
  const auto n = lua_upvalueindex(1);
  lua_pushvalue(L, n);                     // |userdata|
  auto myTypeInst = static_cast<MyType*>(lua_touserdata(L, -1));
  lua_pushstring(L, myTypeInst->str());    // |userdata|string|
  return 1;                                // |userdata|string|
}
```

Note how the table created with `lua_createtable()` didn't get associated with a metatable name the same as if you would have registered the metatable with `luaL_getmetatable()`? This is 100% a-okay because these values are completely inaccessible outside of the closure, but it does mean that `luaL_getmetatable()` can't be used to look up a particular `userdata`'s type. Similarly, this also means that `luaL_checkudata()` and `luaL_testudata()` are also off limits.

The bottom line is that upvalues (such as `userdata` above) are associated with function calls (e.g. `LI_MyType__tostring`) and are not associated with the `userdata` itself. As of now, I'm not aware of a way in which you can associate an upvalue with a value such that it becomes possible to share a metatable across instances.

---

**UPDATE** (2013-10-14) I'm including a small example below that uses a registered metatable (`luaL_newmetatable()`) and also `lua_setuservalue()`/`lua_getuservalue()` for a `userdata`'s "attributes and methods". Also adding random comments that have been the source of bugs/hotness that I've had to hunt down in the past. Also threw in a C++11 trick to help with `__index`.

```c
namespace {

using FuncArray = std::vector<const ::luaL_Reg>;
static const std::string MYTYPE_INSTANCE_METAMETHODS{"goozfraba"}; // I use a UUID here
static const FuncArray MyType_Instnace_Metamethods = {
  { "__tostring", MyType_InstanceMethod__tostring },
  { "__index",    MyType_InstanceMethod__index },
  { nullptr,      nullptr }, // reserve space for __metatable
  { nullptr, nullptr } // sentinel
};

static const FuncArray MyType_Instnace_methods = {
  { "fooAttr", MyType_InstanceMethod_fooAttr },
  { "barMethod", MyType_InstanceMethod_barMethod },
  { nullptr, nullptr } // sentinel
};

// Must be kept alpha sorted
static const std::vector<const std::string> MyType_Instance___attrWhitelist = {
  "fooAttr",
};

static int MyType_ClassMethod_newInstance(lua_State* L) {
  // You can also use an empty allocation as a placeholder userdata object
  // (e.g. lua_newuserdata(L, 0);)
  auto userdata = static_cast<MyType*>(lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(MyType)));
  new(userdata) MyType(); // Placement new() FTW

  // Use luaL_newmetatable() since all metamethods receive userdata as 1st arg
  if (luaL_newmetatable(L, MYTYPE_INSTANCE_METAMETHODS.c_str())) { // |userdata|metatable|
    luaL_setfuncs(L, MyType_Instnace_Metamethods.data(), 0); // |userdata|metatable|

    // Prevent examining the object: getmetatable(MyType.new()) == empty table
    lua_pushliteral(L, "__metatable");     // |userdata|metatable|literal|
    lua_createtable(L, 0, 0);              // |userdata|metatable|literal|table|
    lua_rawset(L, -3);                     // |userdata|metatable|
  }

  lua_setmetatable(L, -2);                 // |userdata|

  // Create the attribute/method table and populate with one upvalue, the userdata
  lua_createtable(L, 0, funcs.size());     // |userdata|table|
  lua_pushvalue(L, -2);                    // |userdata|table|userdata|
  luaL_setfuncs(L, funcs.data(), 1);       // |userdata|table|

  // Set an attribute that can only be accessed via object's fooAttr, stored in key "fooAttribute"
  lua_pushliteral(L, "foo's value is hidden in the attribute table"); // |userdata|table|literal|
  lua_setfield(L, -2, "fooAttribute");     // |userdata|table|

  // Make the attribute table the uservalue for the userdata
  lua_setuserdata(L, -2);                  // |userdata|
  return 1;
}

static int MyType_InstanceMethod__tostring(lua_State* L) {
  // Since we're using closures, we can assume userdata is the first value on the stack.
  // You can't make this assumption when using metatables, only closures.
  luaL_checkudata(L, 1, MYTYPE_INSTANCE_METAMETHODS.c_str()); // Test anyway
  auto myTypeInst = static_cast<MyType*>(lua_touserdata(L, 1));
  lua_pushstring(L, myTypeInst->str());    // |userdata|string|
  return 1;                                // |userdata|string|
}

static int MyType_InstanceMethod__index(lua_State* L) {
  lua_getuservalue(L, -2);        // |userdata|key|attrTable|
  lua_pushvalue(L, -2);           // |userdata|key|attrTable|key|
  lua_rawget(L, -2);              // |userdata|key|attrTable|value|
  if (lua_isnil(L, -1)) {         // |userdata|key|attrTable|value?|
    return 1;                     // |userdata|key|attrTable|nil|
  }

  // Call cfunctions when whitelisted, otherwise the caller has to call the
  // function.
  if (lua_type(L, -1) == LUA_TFUNCTION) {
    std::size_t keyLen = 0;
    const char* keyCp = ::lua_tolstring(L, -3, &keyLen);
    std::string key(keyCp, keyLen);

    if (std::binary_search(MyType_Instance___attrWhitelist.cbegin(),
                           MyType_Instance___attrWhitelist.cend(), key))
    {
      lua_call(L, 0, 1);
    }
  }

  return 1;
}

static int MyType_InstanceMethod_fooAttr(lua_State* L) {
  // Push the uservalue on to the stack from fooAttr's closure (upvalue 1)
  lua_pushvalue(L, lua_upvalueindex(1)); // |userdata|
  lua_getuservalue(L, -1);               // |userdata|attrTable|

  // I haven't benchmarked whether lua_pushliteral() + lua_rawget()
  // is faster than lua_getfield() - (two lua interpreter locks vs one lock + test for
  // metamethods).
  lua_pushliteral(L, "fooAttribute");    // |userdata|attrTable|literal|
  lua_rawget(L, -2);                     // |userdata|attrTable|value|

  return 1;
}

static int MyType_InstanceMethod_barMethod(lua_State* L) {
  // Push the uservalue on to the stack from barMethod's closure (upvalue 1)
  lua_pushvalue(L, lua_upvalueindex(1)); // |userdata|
  lua_getuservalue(L, -1);               // |userdata|attrTable|

  // Push a string to finish the example, not using userdata or attrTable this time
  lua_pushliteral(L, "bar() was called!"); // |userdata|attrTable|literal|

  return 1;
}

} // unnamed-namespace
```

The lua script side of things looks something like:

```lua
t = MyType.new()
print(typue(t))    --> "userdata"
print(t.foo)       --> "foo's value is hidden in the attribute table"
print(t.bar)       --> "function: 0x7fb560c07df0"
print(t.bar())     --> "bar() was called!"
```

Comment: I completely agree, which is why I went to the effort of posting the above. Lua is excellent in its simplicity and speed, but the expertise, examples, or other best practices are terribly hard to find online.

Comment: @niahoo I added a second example that uses a small trick in `__index` to simulate attributes vs methods. The `std::binary_search()` + `static const std::vector<>` should perform well enough in most cases. All of this was dry coded so I don't guarantee anything other than the illustrated concepts.

Answer (score 2):

> how do you create a lua object that only exposes its attributes and not its methods?

If you don't expose methods in *any* way, you can't call them, right? Judging from your example, it sounds like what you really want is a way to iterate through the attributes of an object without seeing methods, which is fair.

The simplest approach is just to use a metatable, which puts the methods in a separate table:

```
-- create Point class
Point = {}
Point.__index = Point
function Point:report() print(self.x, self.y) end

-- create instance of Point
pt = setmetatable({x=10, y=20}, Point)

-- call method
pt:report() --> 10 20

-- iterate attributes
for k,v in pairs(pt) do print(k,v) end --> x 10 y 20
```

> is it possible to not use the colon syntax for OOP in Lua?

You can use closures instead, but then `pairs` is going to see your methods.

```
function Point(x, y)
    local self = { x=x, y=y}
    function pt.report() print(self.x, self.y) end
    return self
end

pt = Point(10,20)
pt.report() --> 10 20

for k,v in pairs(pt) do print(k,v) end --> x 10 y 20 report function: 7772112
```

You can fix the latter problem by just writing an iterator that shows only attributes:

```
function nextattribute(t, k)
   local v
   repeat
       k,v = next(t, k)
       if type(v) ~= 'function' then return k,v end
   until k == nil
end

function attributes (t)
  return nextattribute, t, nil
end

for k,v in attributes(pt) do print(k,v) end --> x 10 y 20
```

> I don't need inheritance, polymorphism

You get polymorphism for free in Lua, without or without classes. If your zoo has a Lion, Zebra, Giraffe each of which can `Eat()` and want to pass them to the same `Feed(animal)` routine, in a statically typed OO languages you'd need to put `Eat()` in a common base class (e.g. `Animal`). Lua is dynamically typed and your `Feed` routine can be passed any object at all. All that matters is that the object you pass it has an `Eat` method.

This is sometimes called ["duck typing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing): if it quacks like a duck and swims like a duck, it's a duck. As far as our `Feed(animal)` routine is concerned, if it Eats like an animal, it's an animal.

> only encapsulation and privacy.

Then I think exposing data members while hiding methods is the opposite of what you want to do.

Comment: In the solution I posted, you can't see the methods when you iterate over the object/table, but you can call the method. Iterating over a list of methods is of little or no value, but iterating over the data that an object has is extremely valuable to a facade (imagine exposing data from C++ as a lua table/object).

Comment: @Sean "In the solution I posted, you can't see the methods when you iterate over the object/table" Only if you use `ipairs`, which will be true for any solution because methods don't typically have integer names.

Comment: See the `__ipairs` metamethod in the answer I posted. Use of functions like `nextattribute()` and `attributes()` is exactly why I posted this answer.

Comment: I'm talking about `pairs`. Regardless: why are you even talking to me? I posted my answer not as a replacement for yours, but in addition, to provide some more approachable ideas for the OP and to clarify a few things that weren't mentioned (such as polymorphism in a duck typing language). I haven't evaluated your answer because *I don't care*. It's not relevant to me. It's for the OP. He won't understand any of it given his current Lua knowledge, but if he's looking for a prebuilt solution, he's got one. Side note: IMO, if people want this kinda stuff in Lua, they should just use Squirrel.